# How to pass classic asp dictionary to .NET RESTful Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, asp-classic

I am having issues passing data parameters from a classic asp application to a .NET Web API.  It seems that no matter what I do I cannot access the parameter inside the .NET web API.  I have included the code I am using below:

The Classic ASP code:

```
Public Function GetResponse (HTTPMethod, ReqURL, QueryParamsOrArgs)

    Set XMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    If HTTPMethod = "GET" Then
        ReqURL = ReqURL & "?" & QueryParamsOrArgs
        QueryParamsOrArgs = ""
    End If

    XMLHTTP.open HTTPMethod , ReqURL, false
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "AuthToken", ServiceUrl_AuthToken
    XMLHTTP.send(QueryParamsOrArgs)

    If XMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        GetResponse = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Else
        GetResponse = ""
    End If

End Function

Public Function TestPOST(url)

    mydata = "value1=1&value2=2&value3=3"
    TestPOST = GetResponse("POST", url, mydata)

End Function
```

In the calling ASP page:

```
dim oDataUtils  : Set oDataUtils = (New DataUtils)
myResponse = oDataUtils.TestPost(ServiceUrl_Base & "EventData/Post")
```

The .NET Web API Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        StringContent sc = new StringContent(value);
        sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        resp.Content = sc;
        return resp;
    }
```

No matter what I send, the value of the parameter "value" inside the api method is always null. Ultimately I would love to be able to send an entire dictionary or parameters to this method, but cannot even get the most simple component (a string) to pass in.  What am I missing here?

My ultimate goal would be for something like this to work:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        // Do something with the dictionary and then return a response...
        StringContent sc = new StringContent("test");
        sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        resp.Content = sc;
        return resp;
    }
```

but I will take either option at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "issue" is: `[FromBody]`

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
```

It is for "simple" type, and translated means, just **one** value. Additionally, the `format` the API expects using `FromBody` is `=value` (notice the missing "key").

e.g.

```
foo=bar //this will fail "null"

=bar //this is good (no key)
```

This will [explain it in detail](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/) even if the topic is about jquery, it will give you insight to the behavior of `FromBody`.

Use [`FormDataCollection`](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/binding-form-data-in-asp-net-web-api)...

Hth....

Comment: Thank you for this... I found another way around this as well, but the FormDataCollection allows the elimination of one step.

`code`
string postdata = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
NameValueCollection NVC = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(postdata);
`code`

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you pass proper json instead of just string ,
form you json like

```
mydata="{'value':'value1=1&value2=2&value3=3'}"
```

You can also pass dictionary of  like

```
var data={};
data.Value1="1";
data.Value2="2";
data.Value3="3";
```

Remember the name of param in action method and name of json key must be same,here 'values

```
mydata={values:data};

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Dictionary<string, string> values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am making my request from VBScript (this is not being done via ajax with javascript) to .NET Web API.  I cannot use the notation for dictionary as you have listed above. I am afraid neither of these options will work for my use unless I am missing something.